# Moving end point of multiple lines in same shapefile using ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, editing

Using ArcGIS 10.2

I require a method of editing multiple lines (selection) that share a common end point and to move the selection to an alternative common end point.

In the picture below I would like to move the light blue selection to a green point at the bottom of the picture.

[image]

Hopefully there is a tool for this that I am unable to find. That can quickly answer this question.

The lines are all in the same .shp file.

Comment: Look for Map Topology on the topology toolbar and use the topology edit tool to shift the end node.

Comment: You'll need to be a bit careful when editing in a topology, even a map topology, try to avoid crossing lines, if lines cross a new node is established at the intersection point and it can be a real pain to resolve - you will need to use the standard edit to fix that.